# Upload File from File system to a Drop area on a webpage - Robot Framework Selenium failing on element not interactable

Tags: robotframework

Robot Framework Choose file is failing to upload the file to drop area on a webpage. We cant use AutoIT as we set up our tests to run in Docker Jenkins.  Is there a way we can achieve this via Execute Java Script ?  Tried many solutions suggested from stack overflow, but no luck. Below is the DOM of our webpage:

```
<form>
 <ul class="form-fields grid" style="display: flex;">
  <li class="row-divider"></li>
  <li class="grid__col-6 required" id="Certification.upload" style="display: flex;">
    <label for="upload">Certification Document Upload</label>
    <div class="Block_block__3KAi_ Block_block__center-content__1bky1" style="height: 6rem; 
     padding: 0.5rem; border-color: rgb(193, 202, 206); 
     cursor: pointer;">Drop file here or click to choose file</div>
    <input type="file" class="hide text-input">
  </li>
  <li class="row-divider"></li>
 <li class="grid__col-6" id="annualCertification.downloadBlankPDF" style="align-content: baseline; display: flex;"><button class="btn btn--outline" style="margin-top: 1rem; outline: none;"><i class="fa fa-download"></i>&nbsp;<span>Blank Certification Form</span> </button></li> 
  <li class="grid__col-12 form_form__horizontal_rulers__3_u4v"><hr class="line-break"></li>
  </ul>
 </form>
```

Tried below Robot Framework Code :

```
   execute javascript  
     ...    var element=document.evaluate("//input[@type='file']", document, null, 
        XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
     ...    element.setAttribute("class", "text-input");
   Choose file  //input[@type='file']  ${EXECDIR}/UI/annual-certification-form.pdf
```

I get no errors, but file not uploaded. We fill in several other attributes on the form, upload a cert document and submit form to complete the request.

Comment: Have you tried [drag and drop](https://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Drag%20And%20Drop)?

Comment: @Dev Drag&Drop in vanilla Selenium (and thus, also SeleniumLibrary) is not always working in these sort of cases.

Comment: Drag and drop also did not work

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the implementation of your SUT - drag and drop events - speficically if dragging a file from computer into browser window is handled somewhat differently than than "choose file to upload" sort of mechanism. Selenium and SeleniumLibrary too  doesn't support that out of the box.

However, SeleniumTestability overrides SeleniumLibrary's `Drag And Drop` keyword to implement a javascript workaround for this.

```
  Drag And Drop      file:${CURDIR}${/}${FILENAME}       id:demo-upload
```

So, that might work directly with your scenario by having the first parameter `file:` to point to the absolute path of the file you want to upload and `id:demo-upload` to appropriate selector for the input ta..

See my acceptance test @ https://github.com/rasjani/robotframework-seleniumtestability/blob/master/atest/draganddropfile.robot

Comment: I tried SeleniumTestability using your example, but I am getting this error :

          Element with locator 'file:../UI/annual-certification-form.pdf' not found.

But the file is there in the FILEPATH specified, I have given absolute path only. Why is that its expecting it to be an element ?

Comment: you most likely have multiple suite files that all import SeleniumLibrary but others wont do it with plugin ..